# Google analytics not working with react app with SSR

Tags: reactjs, meteor, server-side-rendering, react-ga

I'm having trouble getting google analytics running within my react/meteor app. I think the problem is related to me have SSR enabled and then using `ReactDOM.hydrate` to update the app. I've been at this for 24 hours and I'm completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Apologies for the long code. I'm trying to use `react-ga` model from npm. You'll find my attempt find it in `AppClient.js`.

Path: `Client.jsx`

```
onPageLoad(async sink => {
  const App = (await import('../ui/layouts/app/AppClient.jsx')).default;

  ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('react-target'));
});
```

Path:  `Server.jsx`

```
import AppServer from '../ui/layouts/app/AppServer';

onPageLoad(sink => {
  sink.renderIntoElementById(
    'react-target',
    renderToString(
      <AppServer location={sink.request.url} checkIfUserIsLoggedIn={checkIfUserIsLoggedIn} />
    )
  );

});
```

Path: `AppClient.jsx`

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactGA.initialize('MyGoogleId');
history.listen(location => {
  ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

class AppClient extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(11, window.location.pathname);

    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, profile } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="application">
          <Switch>
            {/* Public routes loaded SSR */}
            <IsPublicRoute
              path="/"
              exact
              component={JobsListLandingPage}
              profile={profile}
              loading={loading}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const AppContainer = withTracker(props => {
  const profileHandle = Meteor.subscribe('blah');
  const loadingProfileHandle = !profileHandle.ready();
  const profile = Profiles.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
  const loading = !loadingProfileHandle && !!profile;

  return {
    loading,
    profile
  };
})(AppClient);
```

Path: `AppServer.jsx`

```
const AppServer = props => {
  const { location, checkIfUserIsLoggedIn } = props;
  const staticContext = { checkIfUserIsLoggedIn };

  return (
    <StaticRouter context={staticContext} location={location}>
      <div className="application">
        <Switch>
          <IsPublicRoute path="/" exact component={JobsListLandingPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </StaticRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  I noticed the question is a bit old..  It would help if you added the specific error you are getting.  But just from looking at your code I believe you might have a problem with react-router/history.  I'm assuming `history` uses the DOM, whicih means you will have to check to make sure the DOM exists before calling the history component.  Either way I am also having similar issues, so if you solved your issue, please answer your question and perhaps it can help others :)

Comment: @MatthewStrom. I didn't find a solution to this. Sorry.